# Altium: "Net [] contains floating input pins", but they seem to be connected

Tags: altium

Altium (19.0.10) says the following nets contain floating input pins:

CLR
DIN
LATCH
SCLK

But they seem connected (and on grid) to me (see below). Earlier they were directly connected, no luck. I created an empty project, added this schematic and compiled and got the same errors (and a few bonus errors). Also, I don't want to suppress these errors; I want to fix them.

[image: altium schematic]

Even if I connect the schematic to its parent schematic (see below), I get the same errors.

[image: parent schematic]

Also, I'm getting "Net [] has only one pin..." errors/warnings for these pins (and many others) in my top level schematic. I've checked and everything is on grid (and I think I have my buses/taps named correctly --e.g. SDO1, SDO2... SDO12 go to SDO[12..1]).

Again, I don't want to place directives to silence the errors. Any other comments are welcome (I'm an Altium newb).

Comment: are the ports connected to anything else in the schematic ?

Comment: No. The nets in question are confined to the image I uploaded (I checked with Alt-LMB)

Comment: thats probably the problem - not in front of Altium right now to try. Try connecting something (other than a port, an off-sheet connector, or a wire) to it to see if it goes away.

Comment: https://www.altium.com/documentation/18.0/display/ADES/WorkspaceManager_Err-NetsContainingFloatingInputPins((Nets+Containing+Floating+Input+Pins))_AD

Comment: Building on efox29's comment, Altium takes issue sometimes with unconnected ports or ports that cross several levels of sheets (i.e. sheet within a sheet within a sheet), try connecting the other end of the port to something and see if you still have the same issue. You can set net names to be local or global but Altium wants to see *something* on the other end of the wire, otherwise  **Place->Directives->Generic No ERC** can be used to suppress the error if you do not intend to connect the nets but would like them named.

Comment: drag the ISO7762 to another location ... do all the nets stay attached?

Comment: @efox29 I didn't want to connect this schematic to others yet (trying to debug one schematic at a time), but now that I have, it seems the errors are gone. Thanks. I was wondering why other nets (in this schematic and two others) were not causing errors, but I guess they were all connected differently. Quite frustrated with Altium.

Comment: @Sam Is there a way to compile a single schematic, instead of the entire project? (I cannot find anything in what Altium calls their "documentation"). This seems like a necessary/fundamental operation to me. (If not, Altium should indicate at which level they are considering a net to be "floating").

Comment: @jsotola I already tried this. They stay attached.

Comment: @efox29 hmmm, it seems the errors are back, and I don't know why. I'll upload an image of how the nets are connected in the parent schematic.

Comment: @Ralph are they connected to anything that is not a port, an off-sheet connector, or a wire ? Don't worry about the error until you are finished your design. If you worry about errors for each wire you create, you'll get nowhere because as soon as you create a net, its not connected to anything until you wire it up on the opposite end...so finish your design, then look at errors (especially if you are new to Altium)

Comment: @efox29 They are all connected to pins of a different component.

Comment: @efox29 finishing a design before checking errors is probably the worst way to design anything.

Comment: @Ralph I don't think you can compile a single schematic, as otherwise how would Altium know if a net was truly unconnected or if it simply connected to something on another page? **FYI** Altium doesn't deem a net connected unless there's an actual part on the other end (and even then it still cracks a wobbly sometimes...  I'm currently dealing with some unconnected nets errors at work, but I've got 4 level schematics with a mix of repeats, harnesses and busses)

Comment: @Sam It's simple. Like I said, Altium should indicate at which level they are considering a net to be "floating".

Comment: @Ralph If it helps, when you double-click on the error in the "Messages" window  it's supposed to take you to where the error is (although I've personally had mixed results with this)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the symbol for u_iso7762 has those pins defined as ACTIVE inputs, but nothing connected to those are defined as ACTIVE outputs with exception of power and gnd.

You can fix this by removing the input/output from the component or make sure that the components those nets connect to also have their pins defined as in or output.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show what, if anything, drives the e.g. `CLR1`, `CLR2`, etc. nets.

The warning is simply telling you that no Output type pin is connected to the net; or for the single-pin case, no other connection exists, regardless of pin type.

The underlying system is schematic ERC (Electrical Rule Check).  This is somewhat of an anachronism; it was most important back in the days before hardware description languages, where schematic capture was used primarily for data entry, where outputs must connect to inputs following strict rules, like a single output driver per net, etc.

ERC is not so useful these days, for general interconnection of modules where connection is direct (point-to-point), or not even unidirectional, and it's hardly useful at all for analog purposes (where Passive-type pins, like resistors and capacitors, are interspersed between Output-type pins like op-amp outputs, unless one feels it worthwhile to create variants of all such components to propagate Output-ness and Input-ness through said components), but it's still just useful enough on the whole (or not annoying enough to avoid) that it's not worth disabling/removing entirely.

The error level is controlled under Project Settings (Error Reporting, Connection Matrix); most emit warnings by default.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that this has to do with the REPEAT statement. Have you tried reversing the indices?

Anyways, after also having lots of troubles (especially there not being a 0 index) I have stayed away from the REPEAT statement. Instead, I decided to simply place multiple instances of the sheet symbol (not copies of the sheet). This also allows more fine-grained control over which net goes into which instance instead of relying on indices. I highly recommend this approach even if it means you'll need a little more space in the schematic.