Trace width for 14VSON high current buck-boost converter
I am doing a pcb layout, where I am using TPS63020 buck-boost converter to output 4V from a varying source of 3 to 5 volt. The required peak current of my circuit is 2A (GSM Modem eats the most).
Here is the footprint of the said buck-boost converter
https://www.digikey.in/en/models/2353761
I can't use a trace width of 0.5mm or larger (for the power rails) with this IC, as the pins are dense. What trace size shall I use so that it can go well with an output of 2A peak current?
Normally the circuit won't eat more than 150mA - 200mA current. But I need to keep the peak current as well.
Here is the schematic...

Also I can't connect those 2 VOUT pins (ping 4 and 5) without a net tie, as KiCAD complaints that I am connecting 2 power output pins. Is there any better way than using net tie to solve this?

You may find this related answer helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/717656/311631

You may also find this context helpful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/684351/311631 (I have no direct instruction on KiCAD, but I expect the resolution is similar)

You can safely ignore that "connecting 2 power output pins" thing. That's mainly meant to stop you from connecting together outputs that aren't intended to be paralleled. In general, ERC is just advisory--if you know that what you're doing isn't actually a problem, you can ignore the warnings. DRC is another matter, but ERC isn't usually something you need to pay too much attention to.
KiCad lets you configure the severity of different ERC (and DRC) violations. If you end up in this situation a lot, you can just set that to warning or ignore instead of error. Or you can design your symbols so that they don't do that--I believe KiCad's library conventions say that pins that are supposed to be paralleled should have one pin visible and all the others invisible, set to "passive", and positioned right on top of the visible one, which avoids this problem altogether.
If you just put the two pins in parallel, you should be able to connect both of them to a single ~1.0 mm trace that spans the two of them. That should be more than enough to handle 2 A. If you need more for whatever reason, it wouldn't be a problem to widen the trace a little away from the chip, or just use a fill zone. Or you can just use 2 oz copper.

Often, the IC pins are narrower or pitched closer than the width of the trace you need. This could happen for power traces, and it could happen for impedance controlled traces.
For power pins, usually it's perfectly fine and expected for multiple output pins of a power management IC to be ganged together. Of course, if you have multiple output channels, then you wouldn't do that. But multiple pins for the same output can be connected together.
You have two ways of doing this. One way is to use a thick trace which goes under both pads. At high currents you would need this. 2A might not be high enough for this to be necessary.
The other option is to use a thick trace or a polygon upto the pins, but not touching them. Use regular sized traces to connect the multiple pins to the thick trace or plane. Generally, these joints would be pretty short, maybe 50mils or smaller. The thermal reliefs on Through Hole Pads (and sometimes Vias) are an example you may be familiar with for what that could look like. This second option has the benefit of making soldering your IC by hand slightly less difficult. When the IC pads are in full thermal contact with the thick trace or a power plane, those particular pads can be harder to heat up and you could end up with low quality solder joints at those pins. Of course, if you're soldering with reflow or some other method which preheat the board, this issue is far less pronounced.

Do you mean thermal reliefs on through-holes? I don't know why you would put thermal reliefs on vias.

On through holes and vias. I suppose their use in vias is something of a split opinion. They are needed in some instances though. Filling vias with solder without the thermal relief can be exceedingly difficult, and some vias need to be filled. The vias response to board flexing caused by vibrations is also different in the two cases, though to be honest I've heard both recommendations over the years about which is 'better'

Normally, if you need a filled via, you get it filled and capped during board manufacture. I've never heard of someone filling a via with solder.

I've seen it done at a manufacturer, by their people. The joys of one off applications for exotic environments.
